# Entity Framework CodeFirst Move Data From One table To another

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4.3

I'm using Entity Framework(4.3) Code First Method For My Asp.Net Mvc3 Application.I want to do:Data of table A must be copied (along with some other data) to table B after that when Click Save Button  Tabla A Data will be Removed how to implement this?

Comment: How can you copy data from table A when you just removed it?  Your question makes little sense to me.

Comment: I Edited My Question  Please Review it Mr.Mystere Man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the logical steps to take. Add the following to the Save button's click event:

1. Use a loop to iterate over each row in table A.
2. While looping, add the row information from table A, along with the other data that must be copied, to table B.
3. Verify that the data in table B contains the information you need
4. Use a loop to iterate over each row in table A again, but this time remove each row.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Finally i complete it with ur guidance

Comment: @snowp, I am glad that you were able to complete it. Please mark my response as the answer if it is the guidance that provided to solution.

Comment: 5. Realize Code-First is lame and one should never build a data model this way!

Comment: Code-First is not lame. It is a tool that is very powerful when used at the appropriate times.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should check out Entity Framework Migrations, it is very comprehensive tool for manipulations with database schema. 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/02/09/ef-4-3-code-based-migrations-walkthrough.aspx

Answer (score 0):

May be this Solution Help for SomeOne stuck on this Problem  @Tarzan helped me to complete this

```
IList<OrderTemp> data = _DBService.GetAllOrderTemp();//List

foreach (var result in data)
{
    Order order = new Order()
    {
        OrderId = result.Id,
        CustomerId = result.CustomerId,
        SchoolNameId = result.SchoolNameId,
        Supplier = result.Supplier,
        StatusId = result.StatusId,
        ProductCode = result.ProductCode,
        ProductDescription = result.ProductDescription,
        Color = result.Color,
        Size = result.Size
    };
    _DBService.InsertOrder(order);
    _DBService.DeleteOrderTemp(result);
}
```