# How to move data from one database table to another table of same database using ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I am new to ASP.NET and I want to move data from database table to another table in the same database. I searched a lot but I didn't find such thing in ASP.NET MVC. I have a Table 1 and Table 2 in my `ABC` database and I want to move data from Table 1 to Table 2. I do not have much knowledge to do this thing have you know any blog that can solve my problem. I tried a lot but did not find.

Like 
http://www.codedisqus.com/0QyjVjgPqg/move-data-from-one-listbox-to-another-on-button-click-in-aspnet-mvc.html

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/02/09/ef-4-3-code-based-migrations-walkthrough.aspx

[Entity Framework CodeFirst Move Data From One table To another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12603280/entity-framework-codefirst-move-data-from-one-table-to-another)

Comment: ASP.NET MVC is a **web framework** - it doesn't move data ..... what you're looking for is something in either SQL Server database directly (using T-SQL code), or a **data access** technology like ADO.NET or Entity Framework

Comment: A simple - `INSERT INTO table2 SELECT * FROM table1;` would actually move data from one table to other. If you want to move specific columns, then `INSERT INTO table2 (column_name(s)) SELECT Column_name(s) FROM table1;`

Answer (score 2):

In order to insert data from one table (Database1) to another table(DataBase2).

Check following code:

```
Insert into Database2.dbo.Table1 Select * from Database1.dbo.Table1
```

With due respect to sir ramiramilu :)